# XSLT matching PAGEID to an element ID

Tags: xslt

How would I match two separate numbers in an XML document? There are multiple `<PgIndexElementInfo>` elements in my XML document, each representing a different navigation element, each with a unique `<ID>`. Later in the document a `<PageID>` specifies a number that sometimes matches an `<ID>` used above. How could I go about matching the `<PageID>` to the `<ID>` specified above?

```
<Element>
    <Content>
        <PgIndexElementInfo>
            <ElementData>
                <Items>
                    <PgIndexElementItem>
                        <ID>1455917</ID>
                    </PgIndexElementItem>
                </Items>
            </ElementData>
        </PgIndexElementInfo>
    </Content>
</Element>
<Element>
    <Content>
        <CustomElementInfo>
            <PageID>1455917</PageID>
        </CustomElementInfo>
    </Content>
</Element>
```

EDIT:

I added the solution below to my code. The `xsl:apply-templates` that is present is used to recreate the nested lists that are lost between HTML and XML. What I now need to do is match the PageID to the ID of a `<PgIndexElementItem>` and add a CSS class to the `<ul>` it is a part of. I hope that makes sense.

```
<xsl:key name="kIDByValue" match="ID" use="."/> 
<xsl:template match="PageID[key('kIDByValue',.)]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//PgIndexElementItem[not(contains(Description, '.'))]" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PgIndexElementItem">
  <li>
    <a href="{ResolvedURL/Absolute}"><xsl:value-of select="Title"/></a>
    <xsl:variable name="prefix" select="concat(Description, '.')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="childOptions"
      select="../PgIndexElementItem[starts-with(Description, $prefix)
        and not(contains(substring-after(Description, $prefix), '.'))]"/>
    <xsl:if test="$childOptions">
      <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$childOptions" />
      </ul>
    </xsl:if>
  </li>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 3):

The XSLT way for dealing with cross references is with keys.

**Matching**: A rule matching every `PageID` element that it has been referenced by an `ID` element.

```
<xsl:key name="kIDByValue" match="ID" use="."/> 
<xsl:template match="PageID[key('kIDByValue',.)]"> 
    <!-- Template content -->
</xsl:template>
```

**Selecting**: A expression selecting every `PageID` element with specific value.

```
<xsl:key name="kPageIDByValue" match="PageID" use="."/> 
<xsl:template match="ID"> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kPageIDByValue',.)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Is there any way I would be able to use `<xsl:if test=` and then specify the two?

Comment: @Alejandro I was just wondering if there was a way to match the value of the two using `xsl:if test`

Comment: @jrottier: Yes. You need to use the matching rule, then in the content template add all the necessary code in order to apply such CSS class.

Comment: @Alejandro Sorry. I have a series of <PgIndexElementItem> elements in my XML. Each has an <ID> element inside with a unique number (like my XML example above). Later in the XML there is a <PageID> that contains a number specified to the page. What I want to do is be able to say, if the <PageID> value is equal to one of the <ID> values then apply some sort of css class to it. I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: @Alejandro Alright that makes sense. When I insert the `<xsl:key ...>` section that you posted above into my xsl document, I get an XML Parsing Error: mismatched tag. Expected: </xsl:key>. Any clue why that would be happening?

Comment: @Alejandro So if I have `<xsl:template match="/">All of my HMTL code here</xsl:template>` How would I use the `<xsl:template match ...>` you provided above? I can't get it to work.